# Using PHP if condition inside HTML code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using HTML inside PHP like this.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrSql);$i++)
     $opt.="<option". if($_GET['pId'] == $arrSql[$i][0]){ echo "Selected";} ."value=".$arrSql[$i][0].">".$arrSql[$i][1]."</option>";
```

I have tested it for a long time and it looks correct, but it is showing an error and I don't know where the bug is.

Comment: There is no question. And neither is there a description of the problem.

Comment: Just i edited check back please

Comment: when i run this thing it is showing error.  Personally i think i cannot concat if condition inside the html code like that.

Comment: You should have mentioned the error in your question. Though its obvious that the if statement inside concatenation caused it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use concatenation and `if` together.  Change it to:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($arrSql);$i++) {
     $opt .= "<option"
        . ($_GET['pId'] == $arrSql[$i][0] ? " selected" : '')
        ."value=".$arrSql[$i][0].">".$arrSql[$i][1]."</option>";
```

Comment: @Mugil true, and it probably shouldn't be capitalized either

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the spaces.

Try following:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrSql);$i++)
    $opt.="<option". ($_GET['pId'] == $arrSql[$i][0] ? ' selected="selected" ' : ' ') ."value=".$arrSql[$i][0].">".$arrSql[$i][1]."</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` call is not needed in this place. Your statement only concatenates strings and does not print them.

Additionaly it's not possible to use an `if` statement inside a string concatenation. However the if shortcut, the so called [*ternary*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator is applicable in this situation.

And as pointed out in an other answer there is also a space missing before the *selected* part.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrSql);$i++) {
     $opt .= "<option " 
          .($_GET['pId'] == $arrSql[$i][0]) ? "Selected" : "" 
          ."value=" .$arrSql[$i][0]
          . ">" .$arrSql[$i][1]. "</option>";
}
```

An alternative using `if` that might be more clear is:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrSql);$i++){
     $opt .="<option ";
     if ($_GET['pId'] == $arrSql[$i][0]){
         $opt .= "Selected"; 
     }
     $opt .= "value=" .$arrSql[$i][0]. ">" .$arrSql[$i][1]. "</option>";
}
```

If you want to, you can even inline the array accesses into the string by using curly braces leading to this last line: (more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php))

```
$opt .= "value=${$arrSql[$i][0]}>${$arrSql[$i][1]}</option>";
```

For the future you might want to enable error output in your scripts. This would have indicated the main error.

Comment: always glad to help. If you still have questions, don't bother to ask.